# How can different ingredients be replaced in the Singapore Sling recipe?

Tags: cocktails

I recently was in Singapore, where I tasted some of the most incredible Singapore Slings ever (hint: the best was NOT at the Raffles, but I guess this is a matter of personal taste).

When I came back home, I really wanted to buy the ingredients to prepare it at home, but I found that if I follow the original recipe (well, I do have something different), the taste is different.

I am pretty sure then, that the bars I visited did something different, and I'd like to find out the combination that I like the most.

I used:

```
120ml Generic brand pineapple Juice
7,5ml Cointreau
7,5ml DOM Benedectine 
15ml Generic brand lime juice
15ml Bols cherry brandy
30ml Beefeater gin
10ml Monin Grenadine
Dash of Angostura bitter
```

If I drink it near the ice, it tastes good, while if I do it with a straw from the bottom of the glass, the after taste is... Too much Almond-like, sweet/bitter.

I wonder if `Cherry Heering` really is that "something" here (I know the Bols is cheap, maybe DeKuyper instead?), or if I can substitute `Cointreau` with a Triple Sec, or if I have to choose a better gin.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you shake or stir the mix before tasting? Getting a different taste at the bottom sounds wrong to me.

Comment: I did stir it very well while the ice was inside of it. Yes that's something that bothers me too, but then again, the bars I went in could have just put too much ice in it. Mine had 6 cubes.

Comment: You could try stirring before adding ice to mix the ingredients and again after adding the ice to cool down the mix. Personally i would shake a sling to make sure it is well mixed.

Comment: Well I don't have a proper shaker, so I guess the stirring will have to do... Will try that as soon as I can though

Comment: Try pouring "controlled waterfall style" from one cup to another with a little bit of distance between the cups (basically not lip of cup to lip of cup). Physics could help you shake without shaking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted the recipe to be:

```
120ml Generic brand pineapple Juice
7,5ml Cointreau
7,5ml DOM Benedectine 
10ml Generic brand lime juice
15ml Bols cherry brandy
30ml Beefeater gin
10ml Monin Grenadine
Dash of Angostura bitter
```

Plus I bought a shaker and shook the whole thing with 4 cubes of ice.

I got a very good flavour with a slightly creamy texture, which is very near to what I drank in Singapore. The color is not pink as wanted, but it is a very good cocktail :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace Cherry Brandy and Grenadine with Creme De Noya(Noyeuax).  Creme De Noyeaux is a secret weapon in the world of mixology for use any time grenadine is called for.

Also, don't use crappy pineapple juice.  Generic is ok, but it needs to be high quality.  The difference in taste between bad pineapple juice and good pineapple juice is akin to the difference between a burnt hamburger and a perfectly cooked Filet Mignon.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. May I ask if I just pour 25ml Creme de Noya? Instead of 10ml Grenadine and 15ml Cherry Brandy? Would you also mind to give me some advice on pineapple juice (I live in Germany)?

Comment: You'll have to taste it, but I suspect 25ml might be a bit too much.  I would start with 15ml.  Getting the sweet/sour ration correct is a matter of taste.  I recommend using dole pineapple juice if you can get it.   Good Pineapple juice should be sweet, but have a certain bite that creates a small numbing feeling on the tongue.  It not should not be mild but also should not taste or smell over-ripe.  Also, after re-reading your post I recommend you do NOT build the drink.  Instead, pour the ingredients into a shaker with ice.  Shake until it gets to cold to hold, then strain over fresh ice.

Comment: I see you said you don't have a shaker. Get one- they are <$5 US on Amazon. The procedure you use to make the cocktail is nearly as important as the ingredients.  Bartending/ Mixology, like any art or craft, requires proper tools; and in this case, a shaker is vital.  Mixing with Ice(until the metal shaker gets extremely cold), then straining over fresh ice is the best way to bind the ingredients together and allow for the beverage to stay cold longer with less dilution(at least in the first 15 minutes after preparing the drink).  Using the proper procedure is what separates good from amazing.